# Какую почту указывать в заявку на бесплатную ultimate версию?

Tags: intellij-idea, free, version

Помогите кто подавал заявку, будучи студентов ВУЗа, на получение бесплатной ultimate версии intelliji IDEA, в заявке надо указать свою почту(она у меня на @mail.ru) или какую-то вузовскую на @bsuir.by(ВУЗ БГУИР - Минск, Беларусь) P.S. : смущает фраза при подаче заявки "Я подтверждаю, что указанный адрес электронной почты
в университетском домене корректен и принадлежит мне"

Comment: а что смущает в данном предложении? подаете заявление на ту почту которую выдал универ, все нормально принимается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почту, выданную ВУЗом с его доменом.
Эта почта принадлежит тебе, она просто сделана ВУЗом, все в порядке там. Я также регистрировался, скачивал, все ок.

Comment: в том и дело что мне почту не выдавали с доменом ВУЗа :)

Comment: В ЛК на сайте ВУЗа регался? Возможно там есть логин и пароль ВУЗовской почты. В моем ВУЗе так.